# Python BeautifulSoup with Optional Tags

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

Let me set up an example:

```
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup
    root = '''  <all2>
                    <images>
                        <image>
                            <name> Picture </name>
                            <url> www.thing.com</url>
                        </image>
                        <image> 
                            <name> Another one! </name>
                        </image>
                    </images>
                </all2>
                      '''

soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(root)
for img in soup.all2.images.findAll("image"):
    iname = img.i_name
    iurl = img.url
    print iname
    print iurl
```

Let the tag  be optional. In this case, the second iteration will fail to to find a  tag, and an exception will be thrown:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'renderContents'

I would like for iurl to be None if an optional tag does not appear.  Is this possible?  Or is my XML understanding wrong.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want with 'nameTag'???

The BeautifulSoup documentation clearly tells you to use

```
  iname = img.name.renderContents()
  iurl = img.url.renderContents()
```

Zero reason to invent new syntax or semantics here

Comment: I didn't invent anything.  It's in the documentation. "This idiom lets you access the first <FOO> tag as .fooTag instead of .foo. For instance, soup.table.tr.td could also be expressed as soup.tableTag.trTag.tdTag, or even soup.tableTag.tr.tdTag. This is useful if you like to be more explicit about what you're doing, or if you're parsing XML whose tag names conflict with the names of Beautiful Soup methods and members."

Comment: Where is the documentation about using <tagname>Tag for accessing '<tagname>'?

Comment: Apart from that: you can easily see yourself that None is returned for non-existing tags. And calling renderContents() on None gives you obviously the cited error. Using 'if' is your friend here.

Comment: So the solution is am 'if' or 'try/catch' block?  I had considered that but i thought there would be a better approach.  I changed my code above.  It now returns None when it should, but I still cannot extract the data from the tags without getting the AttributeError.

Comment: this might do it:
 iname = (str(img.i_name.string) if (img.i_name != None) else None)
 iurl = (str(img.url.string) if (img.url != None) else None)